# Git .gitignore to ignore only folder in root directory

Tags: git, gitignore

Here is my .gitignore

```
static/
```

and I have installed git on the folder named `project` there is a folder named `static` and another folder called `app` and inside the `app` folder, there is another folder `static`. The above `.gitignore` ignore both static folders, That is not what I want.

What I want is to ignore the folder `project/static/` not the folder `project/app/static/` How can I do that?

Comment: My git repository has django project in it. So I added project/static/ to .gitignore

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Just add `/` before `static/`, should be like

```
  /static/

# ^ forward slash before the folder name signifies root dir
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and I also Understand how Gitignore actually look ignored filed.

Comment: @DevkotaSagar if you are looking to exclude specific files only in static folder, you can also do something like `/static/*.css` will exclude all files inside root static folder with `.css` extension.